# multiple ng-Options are showing all together as text box Any idea Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiselect requirement, so here what is happening on page load all the multselect values are showing in in select box , How can i show dropdown and if user select the value only that value should display in select..

main.html

```
 <select
        class="form-control"
        multiple
        name="themesList"
        id="themesList"
        ng-model="challengesDTO.themesKyList"
        required
        ng-options="Option.id as Option.text for Option in challengOptions">
        <option value="">
            Select...
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This question isn't clear enough

Comment: all the options are displaying in one select box it should display as dropdown so user can select

Comment: `<select multiple>` doesn't behave like a drop-down. You'll need a custom control for that